# How can I list all processes running in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, pid, diagnostics

I would like to find a way to loop through all the active processes and do diagnostics checks on them (mem usage, cpu time etc) kinda similar to the task manager.

The problem is broken down into two parts:

1. Finding all the processes
2. Finding diagnostics attributes about them

I am not sure even in what namespace to go looking about it. Any help / tips / links is grateful.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Finding all of the processes**

You can do this through the Process class

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
var allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
```

**Running Diagnostics**

Can you give us some more information here?  It's not clear what you want to do.

The Process class provides a bit of information though that might help you out.  It is possible to query this class for

- All threads
- Main Window Handle
- All loaded modules
- Various diagnostic information about Memory (Paged, Virtual, Working Set, etc ...)
- Basic Process Information (id, name, disk location)

**EDIT**

OP mentioned they want to get memory and CPU information.  These properties are readily available on the Process class (returned by GetProcesses()).   Below is the MSDN page that lists all of the supported properties.  There are various memory and CPU ones available that will suite your needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

**Code:**

Add this line to your using list:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Now you can get a list of the processes with the Process.GetProcesses() method, as seen in this example:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Finding all processes is rather easy actually:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processes)
{
    // Get whatever attribute for process.
}
```

Answer (score 12):

JaredPar already pointed out the `Process` class, so I'll just add, that you should be aware, that the class takes a snapshot of the process' information when the instance is created. It is not a live view. To update it you have to call `Refresh()` on the instance.

Also keep in mind, that the process may close while you are inspecting it, so be prepared to catch exceptions and handle them accordingly.

And finally if you call `Process.GetProcesses()` you will also get the pseudo processes "idle" and "system". IIRC they have specific process IDs so you can easily filter them out.

Comment: Thanks for the gotcha. I will be sure to keep this in mind +1

Answer (score 2):

This is how I prefer to access the processes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process.GetProcesses().ToList().ForEach(p =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            p.ProcessName + " p.Threads.Count=" + p.Threads.Count + " Id=" + p.Id);
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this in powershell

1.Finding all the processes

```
get-Process
```

2.Finding diagnostics attributes about them

```
get-Process | where-object { $_.Handles -gt 200 }
```

The above code will return all processes with over 200 handles, you can specify your diagnostic attributes in this manner easily.

For more information on [how to handle processes using powershell see this](http://computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_process.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {   
      Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();`          
   }
}
```

here process arrray contains all the number of process present into it.

Answer (score -1):

What operating system are you using? I take it from your C# tag that it's windows?

If so, check out WMI, particularly the Win32_Process class. Here's the MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx

As well as a couple of usage scenarios here (such as getting a list of processes): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394599(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yes it is windows (It says in the topic).

Comment: Haha sorry, massive overlook on my part!