# How to get duration with the current active processes in c#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to know the window names and duration of the current windows open in c# and get a callback when the windows have closed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list all processes running in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648410/how-can-i-list-all-processes-running-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window title: {2}" duration: {3}" , process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle, process.duration);
}

// i'm not sure if process.duration actually exists but it would be something like that
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) class you can get that information.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public void GetProcessesInfo()
{
    Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (Process process in allProcesses)
    {
        try
        {
            string windowName = process.MainWindowTitle;
            TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - process.StartTime;
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
        }
        catch(System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
        {
            //access to that process was denied
        }
    }
}

void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //a process has exited
}
```