# How can I select a running process in open file dialog style?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I would like to make a process selection with an open file dialog gui, so the user can pick which process they want to terminate.

```
this.openFileDialog1.FileName = "FileName";
```

I've found this in `System.Windows.Forms;`.
Any ideas on how can I solve my problem?

Comment: What are you having a problem with? Getting a list of running processes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I list all processes running in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648410/how-can-i-list-all-processes-running-in-windows)

Comment: I want to get a list or running processes but in a gui, so user can pick a process out of the list.

Comment: Also, a OpenFileDialog control is for selecting files from your hard drive, not anything else.

Comment: @Pera16 If you're asking for a ready built GUI for selecting running processes you probably won't find any open source implementations for that. You'll have to build that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In windows forms add `ListView` to form.
2. Change `View` to `Details` and add 2 `columns` to this ListView.
3. Paste code to `Form_Load` for example.

```cs
foreach(Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
     ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(process.ProcessName);
     item.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, process.Id.ToString()));
     listViewProcesses.Items.Add(item);
}
```

4. Add `using System.Diagnostics;`
5. To kill process make:

```cs
Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(listViewProcesses.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text)).Kill();
```